# Converting to ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm very new to ES6 and here is my first try. Looks like I only need to update the first line. However, I remember reading that 'this' should not be used. I'm confused. Hopefully you can fix the code for me. Thanks!

// current code

```
initialize: function initialize(options) {
  this.item = systemChannel.request('iteminfo:request');
  this.model = new someModel({
    someItem: options.someItem
  },
  {
    parse: true
  });
},
```

Then I'm trying to convert to ES6 syntax
// es6 version

```
initialize(options) {
  this.item = systemChannel.request('iteminfo:request');
  this.model = new someModel({
    someItem: options.someItem
  },
  {
    parse: true
  });
},
```

Is this correct?

Comment: are using transpiler like babel?

Comment: Yes in sublime text, but I wasn't sure if it's working or not. I'm sure it's working but not sure why I wasn't getting any errors. Maybe that code I wrote is in correct ES6 syntax?

Comment: Yes, it is correct ES6. You have examples of shorthand names here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd show your complete code, or at least a complete statement. As it stands, neither of your snippets is valid as a standalone.

Comment: Sure, I'll paste it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks technically valid to me. As for what you intend `this` to be a reference to, it's hard to say 100% without knowing on what you are declaring `initialize`, and if anything else is binding functions for you. Can you post a more full example?

Here's an example of how `this` works on objects with old/new syntaxes. You can run this on the babel repl online, if you want to try for yourself.

```
let obj = {
  fn() {
    return this;
  }
};

var obj2 = {
  fn: function() {
    return this;
  }
};

console.log(obj.fn() === obj); //=> true
console.log(obj2.fn() === obj2); //=> true
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try it. I had an impression that when we use ES6, we should not use the word "return". In your example, you used "return"

Comment: If you use arrow functions, there is an implied return (assuming you don't also provide curly braces to notate a function body), but technically what we are using up above is just shorthand, and not an arrow function.

Comment: Ah, got it. That's great info!